# Issue in Display template mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new in MVC. I have tried to read online articles about how to use display template in collection.

This is my Model

```
public class InsuranceListViewModel
{
    public IList<InsuranceViewModel> InsuranceViewModelList { get; set; }
    public InsuranceViewModel InsuranceViewModel { get; set; }
    public List<InsuranceSummaryViewModel> InsuranceSummaryViewModelList { get; set; }
}
```

SummaryViewModel

```
 public class InsuranceSummaryViewModel
{
    public string FriendlyName { get; set; }
    public int InsuranceId { get; set; }
    public string GroupId { get; set; }
    public string MemberId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> PolicyStartDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> PolicyEndDate { get; set; }

}
```

InsurnaceDisplay.cshtml

```
@model P2PExchange.MVC.Web.Areas.Patient.Models.InsuranceSummaryViewModel
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.InsuranceId)
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.FriendlyName)
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.GroupId)
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.MemberId)
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.PolicyStartDate)
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.PolicyEndDate)
```

_Insurance.cshml

```
 @model Models.InsuranceListViewModel
 @Html.DisplayFor(x=>x.InsuranceSummaryViewModelList)
```

My above code it only displays insurance friendly name not all fields from display template.

Can someone please help/guide me how Can I display correct data on UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `DisplayTemplate` needs to be located in the `/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates` or `/Views/yourControllerName/DisplayTemplates` folder and needs to be named to match the name of the class, i.e. `InsuranceSummaryViewModel.cshtml`

Comment: Thanks a lot Stephen Muecke !!! I did spend half day to resolve this issue but you helped me in few minutes.I did keep my display template in displayTemplates folder but file name was incorrect, I did corrected file and it works.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that there is an override for `DisplayFor` (and `EditorFor`) that accepts template name in case that name of class don't match the template:  `@Html.DisplayFor(x=>x.InsuranceSummaryViewModelList, "InsuranceSummary")` will work if you have `InsuranceSummary.cshtml` in one of the folders that Stephen wrote about